# Retrieving data from wp_posts table in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I am creating admin panel like WordPress in codeigniter, so I need to understand database table relationships in WordPress. There is a database table wp_posts which is used to store posts and pages.
My question is what differentiate posts and pages  in  table.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here a fresh start](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

`posts/pages` and `custom post` types are differentiated by the field `post_type` inside `wp_posts`

```
post_type   varchar(20)         IND Pt1     post
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ ste thanks for help. I have one more question.I want to to display categories and tags by their posts. e.g. : Suppose I have inserted 4 new posts which are having categories and tags. posts will be stored in wp_posts table and categories and tags will be stored in wp_terms. So what is a relation between both tables.

Comment: Thats a common query. I would suggest starting with the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) and following my link above on how Wordpress is structured. 

Tax's have Terms and have a relation to a post_id

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you didn't do your research before coming to SO. Wordpress posts and pages are stored on a table called **tableprefix_posts** where tableprefix depends on what you as a developer decide to name your table prefixes. what differentiation tables and post is post_type, wordpress have the following posts types:

1. Post (Post Type: 'post')
2. Page (Post Type: 'page')
3. Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
4. Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
5. Navigation menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')

Table Structures

[image]

**Post**

Post in WordPress is a post type that is typical for and most used by blogs. Posts are normally displayed in a blog in reverse sequential order by time (newest posts first). Posts are also used for creating the feeds.

**Page**

Page in WordPress is like post, but it lives outside the normal time-based listings of posts. Pages can use different page templates to display them. Pages can also be organized in a hierarchical structure, with pages being parents to other pages, but they normally cannot be assigned categories and tags. If permalinks are enabled, the permalink of a page is always composed solely of the main site URL and the user-friendly and URL-valid names (also referred to as slug) of the page and its parents if they exist. See the Pages article for more information about the differences

all this information is avalable at wordpress.org